# Solve t (Algebra Problem)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was solving a mechanics question and I stuck in this step.

I've to solve $t$ when $20t-\frac{1}{4}t^4-36=0$

Can anyone teach me what method to use to solve this equation ?

Comment: Are you sure it is not $20t^2-\frac{1}{4}t^4-36$?

Comment: @Spenser yes I'm sure .

Comment: Have you been taught how to solve cubic equations?

Comment: Yes . I've been taught

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, multiply the equation by the least common denominator of all the fractions, to get just integer coefficients. You then get

$$80t-t^4-144=0$$

Then multiply by $-1$ and rearrange the terms to get the polynomial in standard form:

$$t^4-80t+144=0$$

Now use the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) to find all the integer  (and rational) roots. In your case, any rational root must be an integer and a factor of $144$. There are many factors, but this is still doable. You will soon find that one root is $t=2$.

If you need all the roots, you then divide the polynomial $t^4-80t+144=0$ by $t-2$, which will be an even division since $2$ is a root of the polynomial. That gives you a [cubic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) from which you can use Cardano's method to find the roots. I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$20t-\frac{1}{4}t^4-36=-\frac{1}{4} (t-2) (t^3+2t^2+4t-72)$$
Hence, $t=2$ is one solution, and there are three other solutions which are the solutions to the cubic equation
$$t^3+2t^2+4t-72=0.$$